# Suppose $\,A\,$ is a $\,5 \times\,$ 8 matrix with $\,\operatorname{rank} A = 5$

Tags: matrices

Just some basic concept questions to clear up some definitions:

> Does $\,Ax = 0\,$ have a non-trivial solution? Why?

My answer to this is no, because to have a rank $5$ that means there is a pivot position in every column and therefore can't have a non trivial solution.

Is this right? I feel as though that logic is somewhat circular.

> Does $\,A^T x = 0\,$ have a non-trivial solution? Why?

I want to say no again, for basically the same reason as above, but I guess I don't know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$rank(A)=5$, hence $A$ has 5 pivot columns in the reduced row-echelon form. As a $5\times8$ matrix has 8 columns, not every column is pivot, hence, there are free variables when solving $Ax=0$.

$A^T$ can be any $8\times5$ matrix with 5 columns. Since $rank(A)=rank(A^T)$, there are 5 pivot columns, hence every column is pivot. As such, there are no free variables and $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

Element118 has already given an answer. I will give in another way.

Here $A$ can be  thought as a linear map from $V_1$ to $V_2$ where $V_1$ is a vector space of dimention $8$ and $V_2$ is a vector space of dimention $5.$

$Rank A= 5$  means by rank-nullity theorem 
$$rank(A)+nullity (A)=8$$
which means $dim Ker A=3$.

Hence there is a non-trivial solution of $Ax=0$

$A^t$ will be a linear map from $V_2$ to $V_1$. Applying rank-nullity 
$$rank(A^t)+nullity (A^t)=5$$ Since $rank(A)=rank(A^t)$ , we must have $dim Ker A^t=(0)$.

Hence $A^tx=0$ will have trivial solution